# PHP blank body page on first time open on firefox on my development server

Tags: php

I really don't know why my web page is always blank in body whenever open a new page in firefox on my development server!

My development server have many web sites! 
Some sites same problem and some sites no problem...

But I'm not working with server administration.

The result of the page is blank body:

```
    <meta http-equiv="Keywords" content="Google je t'aime" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/_design/favlogos.png"/>

        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/_style/styles.css" />

        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/_style/jquery.fancybox.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="/_script/jquery.fancybox-1.2.6.js"></script>




</head>
<body></body>
```

---

Any comment please!

Thanks and Regards!

Comment: Sorry I couldn't post my php code; My project manager will not allow...

Answer (score 0):

Enable error reporting using `error_reporting` and `display_errors`.

Comment: Thanks for ur respond.
It just display some notifications.
No error with the php code.